# What is this problema asking for? I don't understand the question. (set notation, composite relations)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, relations

In the following problem, what does the "circle" between set names represent?  What exactly is this problem asking me to do?

---

**Consider the following relations on Z:**

$R1 = \{(x, y) | y = x + 1\}$

$R2 = \{(x, y) | y = x − 1\}$

$R3 = \{(x, y) | y = 2x + 1\}$

$R4 = \{(x, y) | y = 2x − 1\}$

**Describe each of the following composite relations in set builder notation.**

R1 ◦ R1

R2 ◦ R1

R3 ◦ R1

R4 ◦ R1

R1 ◦ R2

R2 ◦ R2

R3 ◦ R2

R4 ◦ R2

R1 ◦ R3

R2 ◦ R3

R3 ◦ R3

R4 ◦ R3

R1 ◦ R4

R2 ◦ R4

R4 ◦ R4

Answer (score 1):

It represents composition of the relations.  In the problem with $R_a \circ R_b$ you are being asked to find the pairs $(x,y)$ such that there is some $z$ with $xR_az$ and $z R_b y$.  These relations all happen to be bijections-for a given $x$ there is exactly one $y$ such that $xRy$.  So if we want to find pairs $(x,y)$ belonging to $R_2 \circ R_3$ we must have $z=x-1$ and $y=2z+1=2(x-1)+1=2x-1$.  Our answer would be $\{(x,y)\mid y=2x-1\}$  Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

The little circle ($\circ$) is the composition operator. It operates on two relations to produce a third relation, their composition. I guess this is either homework or self-study, in which case I would check your textbook for the definition of the composition of two relations. However, Fejer and Simovici in *Mathematical Foundations of Computer Science* define composition in this way:

> $\rho \circ \sigma = \{(x,z) \mid \text{for some }y, \: (x,y) \in \rho, \text{ and } (y,z) \in \sigma \}$

(although they call it a product and use $\bullet$, noting that the above notation and terminology is also used).

Additionally, here is a link to the [wikipedia article on composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_composition).